# is it possible to call a class constructor and define it's body at the same time?

Tags: java, oop, constructor, initialization

In the below code snippet, I know that in the statement `Counter c = new Counter();`,
a new reference variable is declared and a memory location is placed in it by the new operator, while the class constructor is being called, but I don't understand the rest of it!

Is it actually possible to define the constructor body there, with `{ }` while it's being invoked!
Is it possible to define a method inside a constructor?

```
public class Counter {
  private int counter = 0;

  public int count() {
    return counter++;
  }
}
```

and then in another class we have:

```
Counter c = new Counter() {   
  public int count() {
    super.count();   
    return super.count();   
  }
}
```

Comment: This is callend an anonymous class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at an anonymous class *derived* from a `Counter`.

The body of the derived class is contained within the braces. The default constructor of `Counter` is being called (you can't do anything else for an anonymous class). The `count()` method is being overridden.

The above is more commonly performed with interfaces, and provides Java with something analogous to closures (until java 8, at least)

Answer (score 4):

The second snippet shows an anonymous inner class that extends Counter. It does not define a constructor.

You can't define a method inside of a constructor. Also you can't define a constructor for an anonymous inner class.

Comment: But one *can* use initialization blocks with an anon class.

Comment: @user2864740: yes, you can do that. that's not exactly the same as defining a constructor, though.